# Ошибка 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 36: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x

сразу хочу пояснить, я не пишу на питоне, нужен был RPA нашел на гитхабе, поставил питон 3.8 (windows), пытаюсь выполнить

```py
import rpa as r

r.init()
r.url('https://www.google.com')
r.type('//*[@name="q"]', 'decentralization[enter]')
print(r.read('result-stats'))
r.snap('page', 'results.png')
r.close()
```

получаю ошибку  'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 36: invalid start byte
сам файл *.py в кодировки utf-8, видимо ошибка происходит в недрах init() что сделать, как победить?

Comment: Попробуйте кодировку файла с исходным кодом изменить.

Comment: "нужен был RPA нашел на гитхабе" - как будто все обязаны знать, что такое RPA. Вообще проблема точно не в кодировке файла исходного кода, а скорее всего в получаемых данных. Вообще, добавьте полный текст ошибки в вопрос.